# Inline CSS not working using jade

Tags: css, pug

I'm trying to optimize CSS Delivery as recommended in this google page:

https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/OptimizeCSSDelivery

However, I can't even recreate their basic example in Jade. The following code does not work:

```
html
  head
    title= title
    meta(name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0')
    style(type='text/css')
        .blue{color:blue};
  body
    nav(class='navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top')
    p(class='blue') test
```

The p tag is not picking up the style I assigned to .blue in the style tag. Is this type of inline CSS possible with Jade?

Answer (score 1):

You can't indent the styling. This works:

```
html
   head
   title= title
   meta(name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0')
   style(type='text/css').blue{color:blue};
 body
   nav(class='navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top')
   p(class='blue') test
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried using !important?

```
html
  head
    title= title
    meta(name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0')
    style(type='text/css')
         .blue{color:blue !important};
 body
   nav(class='navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top')
    p(class='blue') test
```

Comment: I have and it does not work. The class blue doesn't pick anything up which means there are no styles attributed to it.